# Trying to Parse Incorrectly Formatted CSV

Tags: java, regex

So, I'm parsing thousands of lines from a publicly available government CSV file. The problem is that they've included commas inside values with double quotes, making it really difficult to consistently parse. The number of matches should be 251. I've tried negating the double quotes, but that also doesn't seem to work.

Example:

```
GS08P12VJP0107,0,0,,,,0,5300.00,5300.00,5300.00,2012-09-21,2012-09-21 00:00:00,2012-11-01 00:00:00,2012-11-01 00:00:00,,047,GENERAL SERVICES ADMINISTRATION (GSA),4740,PUBLIC BUILDINGS SERVICE,VJ000,"GSA/PBS/MTN PLAINS SVS CTR, NORTH DAKOTA FIELD OFFICE",047,GENERAL SERVICES ADMINISTRATION (GSA),4740,PUBLIC BUILDINGS SERVICE,VJ000,"GSA/PBS/MTN PLAINS SVS CTR, NORTH DAKOTA FIELD OFFICE",,,043570956,MIKE AUSTFJORD & SONS INC,,MIKE AUSTFJORD & SONS INC,043570956,UNITED STATES,,9469 138TH AVE NE,,,CAVALIER,ND,,582209505,ND00,7012654255,7012653110,USA,UNITED STATES,PEMBINA,PEMBINA,ND,NORTH DAKOTA,582719745,00,,B,PO,,,,,,NAN,J,FIRM FIXED PRICE,"EXCAVATE WETLANDS AS REMEDIATION AT US BORDER STATION, 10980 I-29, PEMBINA, NORTH DAKOTA.",,,,1,Z2AA,REPAIR OR ALTERATION OF OFFICE BUILDINGS,D,NOT A BUNDLED REQUIREMENT,,,238910,SITE PREPARATION CONTRACTORS,A,FAR 52.223-4 INCLUDED,A,U.S. OWNED BUSINESS,,,,,B,JUSTIFICATION - TIME,USA,,C,NOT A MANUFACTURED END PRODUCT,B,PLAN NOT REQUIRED,F,COMPETED UNDER SAP,SP1,SIMPLIFIED ACQUISITION,SBA,SMALL BUSINESS SET ASIDE - TOTAL,NONE,NO PREFERENCE USED,,NAN,,NAN,,,1,D,,f,N,NO,NO,,X,NOT APPLICABLE,N,,,N: NO,,X,NOT APPLICABLE,X,NOT APPLICABLE,Y,YES,X,NOT APPLICABLE,,,,,,,,NONE,NONE,,,,NAN,N,TRANSACTION DOES NOT USE GFE/GFP,,,X,NO,N,NO,N,NO - SERVICE WHERE PBA IS NOT USED.,,,,,N,NO,X,NOT APPLICABLE,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,SMALL BUSINESS,S,t,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,t,t,t,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,2012-09-21 00:00:00
```

Could somebody please assist? I'm doing this through Java Pattern/Matcher..

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to roll your own parser instead of using a publicly available one? Quoting values that contain special characters is standard for CSV formats, so any parser should be able to handle that without a problem.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a parser?

Comment: Re "*The problem is that they've included commas inside values with double quotes, making it really difficult to consistently parse.*", Quite the contrary. Putting the commas in double quotes is what made it possible for the file to be parsed!

Comment: What about reducing the data to a minimum example, as is customary at SO?

Comment: While I agree with @ikegami, I recognize that, but manually trying to parse it has been a PITA.

Comment: "Do you have any suggestions for a parser?" No, but Google does. Try `java csv library`.

Comment: And comments like yours @Renardo are the reason why I post on SO as a last resort.

Comment: ^^ The same w/ @SeverityOne

Comment: @RyanG Thanks a lot. Yes, I could have looked through data 20 times as large as my screen, just to avoid this. I will update that factor to 50.

Comment: @Renardo, and that sucks, but rather than being curt about it, you could have been like "Hey, next time, please curtail the data instead of posting the whole thing."

Comment: @RyanG And that is exactly what Renardo did in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120615/trying-to-parse-incorrectly-formatted-csv#comment85246850_49120615), and you complained about that too.

Comment: @RyanG Which is more or less what I said. I am glad we agree on content, even if not about language (me not native English speaker). Have a nice time.

Comment: @Andreas, I disagree.

Comment: @RyanG No need to get touchy. Making at least a bare-minimum research effort and reducing your problem to a simple example to save time for those of us trying to answer your question are just basic manners in this community. If someone points out that you could have saved yourself all this trouble by googling three words, an appropriate answer might be "thank you."

Comment: @RyanG I don't see the difference between *"What about reducing the data to a minimum example, as is customary at SO?"* and *"Hey, next time, please curtail the data instead of posting the whole thing"*. I don't see the second as being any nicer than the first, and it does ask you to fix *this* question, not the next one, which was the point.

Comment: @Andreas, I personally do. *shrugs*

Comment: Re "*Do you have any suggestions for a parser?*", Unfortunately, requests for tool recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are some different pattern groups to consider. Breaking your example down into various cases, I came up with the following regex

```
(\"(.*?)\")|(.*?(,))|(.*)
```

The first capture group, `(\"(.*?)\")` deals with values in quotes.

The second, `(.*?(,))` deals with the other cases (no quotes).

The last, `(.*)` is for the final part of the csv, with no ending comma.

EDIT

This post got more comments than I would have ever expected.

Of course the above solution has room for improvement, such as it not considering double quotes and it including the trailing comma in the value. The user mentioned they were trying to solve a problem with pattern / matcher, so with a regex that fits their use case, something like this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(someRegex);
String line = ... // get line from somewhere
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

may be sufficient.

One user suggested Apache Commons CSV which can be found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.5 (latest version at the time of writing).

```
for (CSVRecord record : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(new FileReader(source))) {
    Iterator<String> it = record.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String colVal = it.next();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

See the documentation at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html for practical use cases.

Comment: Thank you! This has been troubling me for months, and I've been trying to get around it. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, but there's nothing wrong like learning for the sake of learning IMO.

Comment: @SeverityOne once you know it, it's obvious but for the newcomers why not suggest libraries ***nicely*** instead?

Comment: @ochi Yes, but even if I just type `java csv`, the first hit I get is of Apache Commons CSV. One step up from writing your own CSV code, is writing your own date handling code. There are too many home-brew solutions, usually with subtle bugs, which have been ironed out in standard libraries.

Comment: Incorrectly handle values with double-quotes (e.g. `"Joe ""The Rock"" Smith",23`)

Comment: @SeverityOne you are missing my point. I agree that pointing out the existence of libraries that do this job, and do it well, is better than writing out your own solution. Even if the OP decided to do it for academic reasons, recommending against writing your own is still advisable.  All of that can be done nicely. No need to be rude or condescending about it.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @ikegami those double, double-quotes would have to be escaped (i.e. `\"`) or the would not be well-formed.  am I correct?

Comment: @ochi Have a look through the comments to the question itself. Ryan incorrectly assumed that commas within double quotes,and he complained about comments that didn't suit him, instead of taking them as constructive criticism. To me, it appears that Ryan has more attitude and stubbornness than is healthy, especially if he expects people to help him. And parsing thousands of files merely as an exercise? I doubt it.

Comment: @SeverityOne - I read them - and you'd be correct in your assertion. That's not my issue tho'.  My issue is the one gripe I see all the time in forums and sites like this: newcomers are afraid to get involved and participate because people immediately reply with snarky/condescending remarks.  It's an entry-barrier.  IMHO, it can be avoided.  We were all newbies here at one point. Let's make it a welcoming place instead (it's what I am saying)

Comment: @ochi, In CSV, it's [more common](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) to escape by doubling the delimiter. (The row in my earlier example encode the values `Joe "The Rock" Smith` and `23`.)  But since there's no official spec, some people use backslash-escaping instead of the classic approach.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for clarifying; perfect highlight for the case to use a library instead of rolling your own version of a CSV parser

Comment: @ochi, I've actually been a dev for about a year (not a total newb, but close enough), but I just struggled with this and fell into the rabbit hole for a little too long. And, I've always got an attitude here because whenever I politely ask for help, I get bombarded with snide, curt remarks. I think you're the one person on here who's recognized this issue in the community, and I wanted to thank you. :-)

Comment: @RyanG you’re welcome; thanks for the feedback. Let’s make this place better for everyone :)